# Is it possible to add a Table of Content into a chapter?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, tocloft, etoc

The Table of Content i want to add to the chapter is the ToC of my thesis. The Document I'm writing is the proposal for the thesis. **So i want to add a ToC to a chapter of my document which is completely independent from the document itself. Is this possible?**

Comment: Does the ToC you want to include already exist as a .toc-file? Or do you just already know the structure and want to show it? If the latter, you could use `enumerate` environments to build this, if the former, you might be able to include that .toc-file (but we'd need more information on it, like which document classes are both documents, did you use any toc-related package in any of them,was `hyperref` loaded etc.)

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for the reply. The ToC doesn't exist already. I did try it with enumerate, but i couldn't get it to the same format as a normal ToC.

Comment: @Stephan And does it have to look exactly like that? If the document doesn't yet exist, there is no point in showing fictitious page numbers, and if there are no page numbers there is no need for the dotted lines you'd see in a typical ToC. Which information do you want to supply except for the chapter and section names (with numbering for convenience)? Which formatting do you miss from just `\begin{enumerate}\item Chapter\begin{enumerate}\item Section\end{enumerate}\end{enumerate}`? We aren't clairvoyant.

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion in the comments, it sounds like you want to make an **outline** with section numbers. With the `enumitem` package, you can define a custom enumerate style. In the example below, `\arabic*.` defines a label type of an arabic number followed by a period, and the asterisk in `label*=' indicates that each label should be appended to the label of the level above. This creates a numbering format of 1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, etc., as you might see in a table of contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\newlist{outline}{enumerate}{6}
\setlist[outline]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{outline}
    \item Introduction chapter
    \begin{outline}
        \item The first section
        \item The second section
    \end{outline}
    \item The second chapter
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

[image: Section outline example]

(I did this earlier this week in my own dissertation proposal!)

Answer (score 0):

@mayhplumb this is almost the same like i would do it. In my solution i tried to get a bit more the looks of a ToC. The only problem is that the numbers of the bold chapters aren't bold. Maybe someone knows a solution for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}


\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*}]
    
    \item \textbf{Intro}
          
          \begin{enumerate}[label*=.{\arabic*}]
            \item First
            \item Second
          \end{enumerate}
            
    \item \textbf{Main}
            
          \begin{enumerate}[label*=.{\arabic*}]
            \item Third
            \item Fourth
            \item Fifth
          \end{enumerate}
            
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]